# Map requests based on each element in an Observable using Retrofit?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, retrofit2

I'm migrating `REST` calls to use: `Observable<T>` instead of: `Call<T>`. For simple stuff, it's mostly straightforward, but I'm a bit stuck with this one...

I've managed to go through pages for one request using this chain:

```
Observable.range(1, 100)
.concatMap(pageNumber -> retrofitApi.itemsObservable(pageNumber))
.takeUntil(itemsResponse -> itemsResponse.list().isEmpty()
.reduce(items, itemsResponse -> items.addAll(itemsResponse.list())
.map(items -> new ArrayList(items))
```

So far, so good, but...what puzzles me is: how to sort out the subsequent steps:

1. For each element in `items`, make another request(s): `retrofitApi.itemDetails(pageNumber)`, which returns element-related data (respecting paging)
2. Add or map the data to the element (of `items`)
3. Return `items` as: `Observable<T>` elements

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out on my own. `flatMap()` seems to be right operator for this case.

This is how full code looks now:

```
Observable.range(1, 100)
    .concatMap(pageNumber -> retrofitApi.itemsObservable(pageNumber))
    .takeUntil(itemsResponse -> itemsResponse.list().isEmpty()
    .reduce(items, itemsResponse -> items.addAll(itemsResponse.list())
    .map(items -> new ArrayList(items))
    // Make single item stream from list
    .flatMap(items -> Observable.from(items))
    // Now flatMap that to similar logic as above for paging
    .flatMap(item -> getItemDetails(item))
    // And return it back to List
    .reduce(/* Basic add and return list reduce */);
```

Comment: suggestion: you can use `.toList()` operator after `.from(items)` to combine `ItemDetails` to List